# Store views are changing once we change page

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, switcher, geoip

We are following [this link](https://www.atwix.com/magento/geoip-magento-store-switcher/) to display store views based on country.

If someone visit site from USA, it will open `us store view` , Canada => `Canada store view`, so on.

We are displaying store view switcher on top as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/). Someone from USA changed store view to Canada store view.

But once he click on any other page (menu, catalog, Product ,cms) it will again display old (USA) store view.

But it should be in same store view until we change it manually.

[image]

**Observer.php :**

```
class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * redirects customer to store view based on GeoIP
     * @param $event
     */
    public function controllerActionPostdispatch($event)
    {

        if (!empty($_GET['___from_store'])) {
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($_GET['___store']);
        } else {
            $geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
            $cnCode = $geoIP->getCountry();
            // echo $cnCode;
            // echo $cnCode='IN';
            switch ($cnCode) {
                case "US": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('usa');
                    break;
                }
                case "IN": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('india');
                    break;
                }
                case "CA": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('canada');
                    break;
                }
                case "UK": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('europe');
                    break;
                }

                case "AU": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('australia');
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not test this solution yet, but I think it should work:

```
class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * redirects customer to store view based on GeoIP
     * @param $event
     */
    public function controllerActionPostdispatch($event)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Session $session */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if (!empty($_GET['___from_store'])) {
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($_GET['___store']);
            $session->setData('current_country', $_GET['___store']);
        } else {
            $geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
            $cnCode = $session->getData('current_country') ? $session->getData('current_country') : $geoIP->getCountry();
            // echo $cnCode;
            // echo $cnCode='IN';
            switch ($cnCode) {
                case "US": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('usa');
                    break;
                }
                case "IN": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('india');
                    break;
                }
                case "CA": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('canada');
                    break;
                }
                case "UK": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('europe');
                    break;
                }

                case "AU": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('australia');
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No need to test your solution, your solution always worked for me. you are golden devoloper. thanks a lot.